# Python requests - get json data with pagination

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have to fetch data from and endpoint:

```
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

which return a list of pages, structured with pagination, like so:

```
{'pages': {'last': None,
           'page': 1,
           'pages': 35,
           'per_page': 20}
```

How do I get all the pages, until the very last one?

Comment: unfortunately no, sorry...

Comment: @DeepSpace how would you write it?

Answer (score 1):

It tells you the current page and the total number of pages, and I assume the page # is part of the url.

As such, this can be solved with a `for` loop:

```
url = 'secret_url?page={}'
page_number = 1
data = requests.get(url.format(page_number), headers=headers).json()
total_pages = data['pages']['pages']
for page_number in range(page, total_pages + 1):
    data = requests.get(url.format(page_number), headers=headers).json()
    # do something with current page
```

Of course this can be abstracted more, use this as a push in the correct direction.